# Make touchesBegan method work for a specific view/image

Tags: ios, swift, object, touch, touchesbegan

I've been searching on google for this but couldn't find an answer.

I want to use TouchesBegan but on a specific view, so that when I press something on another view it doesn't start the game. (I want to create multiple levels for my game, but, I don't want to have to go through spritkit) Basically, to summarise, I want to have the TouchesBegan function on one view, but not the other/ is there any way to turn TouchesBegan off via a statement?

Thank you in advance for your answers / or sample code would be great :)

Best,
Samson S.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // First touch to start the game
    if gameState == .ready {
        startGame()

    }


    audioPlayerNine.play()
    audioPlayerTwo.stop()
    clockLabel.isHidden = false
    bestTimeLabel.isHidden = false
    startText.isHidden = true
    bgImageTwo.isHidden = true
    bgImage.isHidden = false
    rText.isHidden = true
    fText.isHidden = true
    iText.isHidden = true
    bgImageThree.isHidden = true
    periodText.isHidden = true
    audioPlayerFour.stop()
    restartText.isHidden = true
    audioPlayerFive.stop()
    audioPlayerFive.currentTime = 0
    lineImage.isHidden = false
    lineImageTwo.isHidden = false
    periodTextTwo.isHidden = false
    self.rTextTwo.isHidden = false
    self.iTextTwo.isHidden = false
    self.fTextTwo.isHidden = false
    levelLabel.isHidden = false
    audioPlayerSeven.play()
    audioPlayerSeven.volume = 0.3
    audioPlayerSix.stop()
    audioPlayerTen.play()
    audioPlayerTen.volume = 0.2
    audioPlayerNine.volume = 1.5
    eText.isHidden = true
    eTextTwo.isHidden = false
    bgImageMenu.isHidden = true
    resumeButton.isHidden = true
    restartButton.isHidden = true
    mainMenuButton.isHidden = true
    muteButton.isHidden = true
    unMuteButton.isHidden = true
    menuLine.isHidden = true
    menuLineTwo.isHidden = true
    bestTimeLabel.isHidden = true
    imagewhite.isHidden = false
    imagewhiteTwo.isHidden = false
    menuButton.isHidden = false
    bestLabel.isHidden = true





    if let touchLocation = event?.allTouches?.first?.location(in: view) {
        // Move the player to the new position
        movePlayer(to: touchLocation)

        // Move all enemies to the new position to trace the player
        moveEnemies(to: touchLocation)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

touchesBegan() is a method defined by NSResponder, and each UIView in your app is an NSResponder. That means that the touchesBegan() method, in your code, *already* works for a specific view.  If you look at the class the code above is it a part of, it is like a UIView or viewController, and this touchesBegan() method receives touches anywhere inside that view.

In programs with different views, you can have different touchesBegan() methods, one for each view (or one for each view with significant touch actions). These methods can accomplish different things -- one could start the game, one could move pieces in the game, etc.

In general, touchesBegan() is useful for situations (and views) where you want to track where and how your user drags across the view. If you are interested only in if an element of your screen display has been touched in order to trigger a single action (like starting a game), a UIButton (a specific type of view) is often a more convenient approach than implementing your own touch handler.  [Here's a very simple tutorial](http://www.danieledonzelli.com/ios/uibutton-tutorial/) to UIButtons in Swift and iOS. In your case, the button's `state` (whether it's clickable or disabled) could be set when `gameState == .ready`) and the button's `action` (what happens when the button is clicked) could be a call to `startGame()`.